# MySQL - Delete duplicate records but keeps XX records

Tags: mysql

My problem is that I want to delete duplicated records but keeps XX latest records. For example:

| id | ean | price | price_type | country | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345678 | 19.99 | b2c | US | 2022-03-30 |
| 2 | 12345678 | 18.99 | b2c | US | 2022-03-28 |
| 3 | 12345678 | 17.99 | b2c | US | 2022-03-26 |
| 4 | 11122233 | 146.99 | b2b | US | 2022-03-30 |
| 5 | 11122233 | 150.99 | b2b | US | 2022-03-28 |
| 6 | 11122233 | 170.99 | b2b | US | 2022-03-26 |
| 7 | 11122233 | 180.99 | b2b | US | 2022-04-01 |

Desired results - keeps 2 latest records:

| id | ean | price | price_type | country | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345678 | 19.99 | b2c | US | 2022-03-30 |
| 2 | 12345678 | 18.99 | b2c | US | 2022-03-28 |
| 4 | 11122233 | 146.99 | b2b | US | 2022-03-30 |
| 7 | 11122233 | 180.99 | b2b | US | 2022-04-01 |

Which query statement should I make to do this? Thank you!

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is precise MySQL version? – Akina
>
> MySQL 5.7 – nphuly

```sql
DELETE t0
FROM test t0
JOIN ( SELECT t1.id, COUNT(*) cnt
       FROM test t1
       JOIN test t2 ON t1.ean = t2.ean AND t1.valid_to <= t2.valid_to
       GROUP BY t1.id ) t3 ON t0.id = t3.id
WHERE t3.cnt > 2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3284d0a012272813c1fbd6121bfd51b3

Answer (score 0):

it is support MSSQL 8.0 version or above

use `ROW_NUMBER` with PARTITION and get your result

Get only 2 record of each ean

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
SELECT id,ean,price,price_type,country,valid_to,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY valid_to ORDER BY ean,valid_to) AS RNO 
FROM tablename
)main 
WHERE RNO < 3
```

if you want to delete then use this

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id IN (
    SELECT Id FROM (
            SELECT id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY valid_to ORDER BY ean,valid_to) AS RNO 
            FROM tablename
        )main
        WHERE RNO > 2
        )
```

Comment: OP needs not select but delete

Comment: @Akina added both code delete and select.

Comment: what happened can you explain please @Akina.

Comment: it's working find because first getting id after delete it so working fine.

Comment: Oops, I miss that you use double subquery.

Comment: so what you thinks it's right or wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243227/discussion-between-piyush-kachhadiya-and-akina).

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef1a0e8faf610bc352ff06b1934789d8